# Does Firebase Support Appium tests

Tags: android, firebase, testing, appium

We are using `Appium` test to test our android apps. As I was researching about the cloud test labs, I didn't find any documentation regarding `Firebase` database supporting `appium` tests.

1. So, does `Firebase` support `Appium` tests?

Answer (score -10):

Finally i found the answer Yes Firebase supports Appium Tests, for more details please refer this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start

Comment: Are you mixing Python with Appium? Because as far as I understand, Firebase Test Lab does not support Appium.

Comment: please can you refer to the part of the docs page you posted above that talks about appium cuz I could not find it

Comment: I actually clicked ctrl+f and searched for "Appium" but could not find it.

Comment: This is not related to your question at all.